# On begin Cursor Over / End fires continuously

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to do a "show item info in widget on mouse overlap" thingy, and it works so-so. It seems that the OnBeginCursorOver/End fires continuously, causing the widget to flicker (on, off, on, off....)? Now, if I disconnect the OnBeginCursorOver, OBCO fires once and the widget shows fine. Of course, it is no longer removed.

Its a very simple setup. Widget Visibility is BOUND to a BOOL on my Player Character which I toggle TRUE on OBCO, and FALSE on OECO.

Anyone?
[image]

Comment: Just add Breakpoints on both Events and debug it. This is too broad/ unclear, could be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with visibility settings. Works fine now.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I have set the visibility checkbox to block in collision settings but it still happens